# Android mediaPlayer Progressive Download "Connection Reset By Peer"

Tags: java, android, http, media, spark-java

I'm having an issue with android MediaPlayer, I was first caching the the whole song into the memory before playing it, Then I decided to stream the song from my api written in SparkJava. So now it works fine If I'm trying to seek to a loaded point, otherwise It just stops. and Produces this in the API server:

```
    org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:286)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:393)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.completeWrite(WriteFlusher.java:349)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$3.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:133)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:295)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:54)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:113)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:79)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:50)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:484)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:264)
```

This is code used at API part:

```
public static Object postAudioResponse(Request request, Response response) {
    try ( OutputStream os = response.raw().getOutputStream(); BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os))
    {
        File mp3 = new File("C:\\FTPServer\\" + request.queryParams("dir"));
        String range = request.headers("Range");
        if (range == null) {
            response.status(200);
            byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Paths.get("C:\\FTPServer\\" + request.queryParams("dir")));
            response.header("Content-Type", "audio/mpeg");
            response.header("Content-Length", String.valueOf(bytes.length));
            System.out.println(response.raw().toString());
            HttpServletResponse raw = response.raw();
            raw.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
            raw.getOutputStream().flush();
            raw.getOutputStream().close();
            return raw;
        }
        int[] fromTo = fromTo(mp3, range);
        int length = fromTo[1] - fromTo[0] + 1;
        response.status(206);
        response.raw().setContentType("audio/mpeg");
        response.header("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
        response.header("Content-Range", contentRangeByteString(fromTo));
        response.header("Content-Length", String.valueOf(length));
        final RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(mp3, "r");
        raf.seek(fromTo[0]);
        writeAudioToOS(length, raf, bos);
        raf.close();
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        return response.raw();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
        return gson.toJson(new StandardResponse(StatusResponse.ERROR, e.toString()));
    }
}
```

And this is my API HTTP Response(String Format)

```
HTTP/1.1 206 
Date: Wed, 04 Mar 2020 19:39:45 GMT
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Range: bytes 4767443-4775635/8897707
Content-Length: 8193
```

I tried multiple things, Changing the header, Validating the header multiple times, Tried ExoPlayer, I even checked android source code for the HTTP part and it seemed correct.

Android Code:

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(Api.getSongSource(songName));
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

Note:The exception happens before I send the new HTTP Response with the Content in specific Range.
Thanks.

*** UPD ***

I solved this issue in the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed the above bug by doing the following

*Client Side
Instead of using mediaPlayer in android native SDK, I used ExoMedia(Which is an interface for ExoPlayer but has the same functionalities as mediaPlayer)

*Server Side

After using ExoMedia, I started to notice something, When I seeked to a point that is not yet loaded, It played from that part for a very small fraction of time, 
Maybe 50 millisecond, So I started digging around and Found out the following.

When The server Receives a request with **Range**, Server would look for the from, then send a response with the data **[From, From + Chunk]**.

My Chunk was equal to 8192, Upon **increasing** the chunk part, I could notice that the song played for **longer**. So Instead of sending the **[From, From + Chunk]** and waiting for the **ExoMedia** to ask for the next part.

I sent the whole [From, End of song]. And this fixed my bug.
.